# What is the difference between regular and Async methods (OnGet vs OnGetAsync)

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I started learning how Razor Pages work, tutorials mention OnGet and OnPost, and also mention that we have async options too: OnGetAsync and OnPostAsync. But they don't mention how they work, obviously they're asynchronous, but how? do they use AJAX?

```
public void OnGet()
{
}


public async Task OnGetAsync()
{
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with AJAX. In terms of being *asynchronous*, this means such methods (handlers) can use the [`async`/`await`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/) pattern from C# 5+. Although it refers to an older version of ASP.NET MVC, [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/performance/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4) might help explain the benefits of using `async`/`await` here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no actual difference between `OnGet` and `OnGetAsync`.  `OnGetAsync` is just a naming convention for methods that contain asynchronous code that should be executed when a GET request is made. You can omit the `Async` suffix but still make the method asynchronous:

```
public async Task OnGet()
{
    ...
    await ....
    ...
}
```

Asynchronous methods are ones that free up their threads while they are executing so that it can be used for something else until the result of the execution is available. You can read more about how asynchronous methods work here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/#BKMK_WhatHappensUnderstandinganAsyncMethod

You can't have an `Onget` *and* an `OnGetAsync` handler in the same Razor Page. The framework sees them as being the same.

Comment: I'm new to Razor pages and this is a little confusing. Normally each connection should be served in a separate thread by IIS so like I understand from your saying that OnGet and OnGetAsync actually functions the same way, asynchronously in a separate thread. I see many samples calling an asynchronous function and awaiting for it to finish, basically blocking the calling thread. Why are they doing that? There is no message queue to process like in a usual Windows desktop application, why are they creating again a new thread and consuming system resources unnecessarily? Even in MS samples u c it

Comment: @Mike: Is there any advantage of using OnGetAsync over OnGet. For example if my razor page has only one method .i.e OnGet to display data and no other operation. In this case which one it better to call

Comment: The -async makes sense for people using Tasks or DB calls from a razor page that spins an IO call