# ASP.NET Core 2.2 Razor Pages why does OnPost() work, but OnPostAsync() doesn't?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

Please would someone explain why OnPost() works, but OnPostAsync() doesn't. Another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52895741/what-is-the-difference-between-regular-and-async-methods-onget-vs-ongetasync) said there wasn't a difference, but seemingly there is...

This works

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost()
{
   LoggedInUser = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
   if (LoggedInUser == null)
      SetPageStatusMsg("No user logged in");
   else
      SetPageStatusMsg($"{LoggedInUser.UserName} is logged-in");

   return Page();
}
```

but this doesn't even get called

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
{
   LoggedInUser = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
   if (LoggedInUser == null)
      SetPageStatusMsg("No user logged in");
   else
      SetPageStatusMsg($"{LoggedInUser.UserName} is logged-in");

   return Page();
}
```

Perhaps it's a Core 2.2 thing, but there's no error as we never make mistakes in Core 2.2 ;-)

Comment: _"doesn't work"_ - in what way?

Comment: thanks for comment. I've clarified: It doesn't seem to get called - no indication why

Comment: If you don't mind answering, how exactly are you calling it?

Comment: Just tested it against asp.net core 2.2 and everything works fine. Do you get 404?

Comment: Can you add the full code? (with the surrounding class/controller)

Comment: There is in fact no difference. Although, you can only have one or the other, if it's not obvious. If it's not being used, there must be some issue that's not transparent from the little that you've provided here. Try posting your full codebehind, as @hugo suggested.

Comment: Pay also attention that dotnet core is convention based.  You should check if "OnPost" is interpreted as a "HttpPost" while "OnPostAsync" could be not interpreted and then is the default HttpGet of your controller...

Comment: Do you have them both in your code at the same time? As @ChrisPratt stated, they are seen as the same thing so now the framework has to choose one if they're both there.

Answer (score -2):

I would recommend upgrading ASP.NET Core 2.2 to Core 3.0., and rebuilding the project. It should help.

At the same time, please make sure that normal handler and Async handler are not used at the same time, below some more information on that.

As this source stated: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/handler-methods

"OnGet and OnGetAsync are the same handler. Cannot have both in the same page. If you do, the framework will raise an exception:

InvalidOperationException: Multiple handlers matched. The following handlers matched route data and had all constraints satisfied:

Void OnGetAsync(), Void OnGet() "

From my experience, I tried using OnPostAsync and OnPost handler at the same time, and I got the following error:

An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request. InvalidOperationException: Multiple handlers matched. The following handlers matched route data and had all constraints satisfied: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult OnPost(),System.Threading.Task'1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult] OnPostAsync()

So, to solve this issue you could use either use one OnPostAsync or  one OnPost.
That is my idea, please tell me if you have something more to it.
Here is more information: https://codingblast.com/asp-net-core-razor-pages-handlers/